# Symfony: LuckyNumber Controller Not Found

Tags: symfony, controller

I am a Symfony newbie working through the "Create your First Page" tutorial. The tutorial instructs readers to "create a "Controller class" and a "controller" method inside of it..." Does that mean create a text file and paste the provided code into a LuckyController.php file? Or is there another method?

When I try the LuckyController.php from localhost, I get the error:

```
[1/2] ReflectionException: Class AppBundle\Controller\BlogController
does not exist
```

Here's the code:

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

<?php

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/lucky/number")
 */
public function numberAction()
{
    $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

    return new Response(
        '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
    );
 }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using so we can help!

Comment: I've added the controller code to the original question.

Comment: The error is about `BlogController`, check your `app/config/routing.yml`.

Comment: Edit your post to show the message please.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP tag needs to go before your namespace and use statements:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: That allowed be to get past the controller error. Now the problem is "No route found for "GET /lucky/number". I thought there was a route.

Comment: What are you typing in your browser URL? Can you show the `exact` URL please.

Comment: Can you try using this URL instead: `http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/lucky/number` and hopefully that will give you some debugging info. Something must be missing.

Comment: No luck. Here is the error message: 'No route found for "GET /lucky/number"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »'

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct Symfony project, and you editing the correct file? You might want to start another project from scratch. Just cut and paste the code; it shouldn't take long.

Comment: I created a new project and followed an error about missing the \Controller\Controller Bundle, was able to successfully complete the first stage of the Symfony "LuckyNumber" tutorial.